# Method undefined from injected service in NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

NestJS: Function create123 shows but through error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create123')

Here is the constructor

```
\`export class AuthenticationService {

constructor(

    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
    private readonly jwtService:JwtService,
    private readonly configService:ConfigService

) {} \`

\` try {
const createdUser = await this.usersService.create123(data)

       console.log('inside',createdUser)
       createdUser.password = '';
      return createdUser;
    }`
```

I try to give user service in authentication module. But it did not work.

Expecting: call register method & working

Comment: Can you share the tsconfig.json and UserService?

Comment: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false
  }
}

Comment: Can you add the tsconfig in the question as a snippet please?

Comment: import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import CreateUserDto from './dto/create-user.dto';
import User from './entities/user.entity';
 @Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>
  ) {}
    throw new HttpException('User with this email does not exist', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }async create123(userData:CreateUserDto ) {
    const newUser = await this.usersRepository.create(userData);
    await this.usersRepository.save(newUser);
     return newUser;
  }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be happened because of circular dependency. (A needs B AND B needs A).

Please read [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

Comment: Yes it works . now i have new error with repository

Comment: Here is issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71693917/nestjs-y-typeorm-built-in-repository-undefined   @Mohammad MohammadAlian