# NestJS y TypeORM: built in Repository undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

i did Inject Repository(User) but it did not work for me .

i want to call  : this.users Repository.create

but give this error :
Type Error: this.users Repository.create is not a function

......

i did Inject Repository(User) but it did not work for me .

i want to call  : this.users Repository.create

but give this error :
Type Error: this.users Repository.create is not a function

Service :

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable,forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/authentication/authentication.service';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import CreateUserDto from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import User from './entities/user.entity';
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => AuthenticationService))
    // @Inject(User)

    // private usersRepository: Repository<User>
    @InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
    private readonly authenticationService: AuthenticationService,


  ) {}

  async getByEmail(email: string) {
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return user;
    }
    throw new HttpException('User with this email does not exist', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }

  async getById(id: number) {
    const user = await this.usersRepository.findOne({ id });
    if (user) {
      return user;
    }
    throw new HttpException('User with this id does not exist', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }

  async create(userData: CreateUserDto) {

    const newUser = await  this.usersRepository.create(userData);

     await this.usersRepository.save(newUser);
    return newUser;
  }
}
```

Module :

```
import { Module,forwardRef } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './users.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import User from './entities/user.entity';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { AuthenticationService } from 'src/authentication/authentication.service';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { JwtModule, JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
 
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),JwtModule.register({})],
  providers: [UserService,AuthenticationService,ConfigService],
  exports: [UserService,AuthenticationService,ConfigService],
  controllers:[UsersController]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

Entity :

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
 
@Entity('User')
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id?: number;
 
  @Column({ unique: true })
  public email: string;
 
  @Column()
  public name: string;
 
  @Column()
  public password: string;
}
 
export default User;
```

Comment: In your `UserService` constructor, where is the declaration of the `AuthenticationService` that you're injecting via forwardRef?

Comment: i comment it . but with that also not work

Comment: now after update userService but still not work @Jay McDoniel thanks for help. should i try something else

Comment: i found a solution by creating custom repository and extend with built in works fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by creating a custom repository and extend it with built in works fine.

Here is link :
https://clownhacker.tistory.com/250

I think it happened because I did changes with my entity class, I hope it will help someone.

Comment: If possible, try to include pertinent detail from your external links in your post itself, so that the answer does not become invalidated in the future, if the third party host goes offline.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case in `this.repository`, `this` was not pointing to correct instance. Used `bind` to fix it.